# Validación campo e-mail en godot

Tags: validación, email

cómo están?
Estoy intentando validar un input en si es un mail valido en godot. Para ello tuve que usar una expresión regular y ver si lo que tengo ahi es un email.
Al ingresar los datos en el input y registrarme ese print en la funcion me da un objeto null..

```
func email_validate(email):
    var regex = RegEx.new()
    regex.compile("[^@-.w]|^[_@.-]|[._-]{2}|[@.]{2}|(@)[^@]*1")
    var xz = regex.search(email)
    if xz:
        print(xz)
    else:
        print(xz)
```

Answer (score 0):

El método `regex.search` devuelve null cuando no encuentra coincidencias.

El problema es tu expresión regular. Para empezar estás utilizando `|` que significa ó (disyunción). Por tanto tu expresión regular va a coincidir una de estas cosas:

- `[^@-.w]`: Aquí hay otro problema `@-.` parece un rango de caracteres, pero estaría fuera de orden. Esto provoca un error que impide que tengas coincidencias. *Debería salir un error al ejecutar.*

  Si quieres hacer un rango de caracteres tendría que ser `.-@` queriendo decir todos los caracteres entre el `.` y la `@`. De lo contrario, te recomiendo poner el `-` al final. En todo caso, esta expresión solo coincide un símbolo.
- `^[_@.-]`: Esta expresión solo coincide un solo símbolo, con la condición que esté al inicio de la cadena de texto (debido al `^`).
- `[._-]{2}`: Aquí coincides dos símbolos que sean `.` o `_` o `-`.
- `[@.]{2}`: De nuevo dos símbolos, que sean `@` o `.`.
- `(@)[^@]*1`: Aquí coincides una `@` (agrupada), seguida de algo que no sea una `@` cero o más veces, seguida del símbolo `1`.

Así que incluso corregido el error de `[^@-.w]`, tu expresión regular no parece ser util para una dirección de email.

---

Cómo hacer una expresión regular que valide una dirección de email es más complicado

Por un lado, lo que viene después del `@` es una dirección de internet o un nombre de dominio, así que para capturar el estándar tendrías que tener las reglas para validar esas cosas.

Por otro lado que una dirección de correo sea valida, no significa que exista. La única verdadera validación es enviar un correo con un enlace para que el usuario navegue (y luego viene el tema de hacer una URL única para el usuario, e invalidarla si pasa mucho tiempo), lo cual es demasiado para la validación de un formulario.

*Además puede que no quieras reconocer cualquier dominio. Solo dominios validos y bien conocidos. O al menos que no sean de primer nivel (es decir, que `test@com` no sea valido). Pero esas reglas adicionales te las dejo a tí.*

---

Mi consejo es mantener las reglas simples. Quieres una serie de símbolos que no tengan `@` (`[^@]+`), seguidos de `@` (`@`) seguidos de otra serie de símbolos que no tienen `@` (`[^@]+`). Es decir: `[^@]+@[^@]+`.

O si quieres algo más seguro, puede ser esto:

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_\u0060{|}~-]+@([^:/]+)$
```

Ahí dice que:

- `^`: al principio del texto.
- `[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_\x60{|}~-]+`: hay uno o más símbolos que son alfanuméricos o uno de estos `.!#$%&'*+/=?^_\u0060{|}~-`. Nota: estoy utilizando `\u0060` porque no puedo poner un acento grave sin dañar el formato en este sitio.
- `@`: seguidos de `@`.
- `([^:/]+)`: seguidos de uno o más símbolos que no tengan `:` ni `/` (agrupado).
- `$`: y ahí termina el texto.

Tenemos este grupo `([^:/]+)` porque esto nos permite extraer la dirección de internet o dominio, que podemos luego validar por otros medios.

---

Un nombre de dominio sería `[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?`: que significa:

- `[a-zA-Z0-9]`: un símbolo alfanumérico.
- `(?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?`: opcionalmente seguido de:

  - `[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}`: de 0 a 61 símbolos que pueden ser alfanumérico o `-`.
  - `[a-zA-Z0-9]`: Seguido de un símbolo alfanumérico.

Es decir, una cadena de hasta 63 símbolos que pueden ser alfanumérico o `-`, pero no terminan ni empiezan en `-`.

Luego, un dominio sería

```
^[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$
```

Es decir, un nombre de dominio seguido de cero o más `.` y nombre de dominio. Es decir, una cadena de nombres de dominio separados por `.`.

Nota: Esto además cubre IPv4. Sin embargo no cubre IPv6. Espero que no haga falta.

---

Ah, si, Godot.

Podemos hacer nuestra expresión regular para dominios de esta forma:

```
var domain_regex := RegEx.new()
domain_regex.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?(?:\\.[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?)*$")
```

Sin embargo, dime si no es más más fácil de entender de esta forma:

```
var domain_regex := RegEx.new()
var domain_name_regex_str := "[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?"
domain_regex.compile("^" + domain_name_regex_str + "(?:\\." + domain_name_regex_str + ")*$")
```

Y ya con esto podemos terminar nuestra validación:

```
func _ready():
    print(email_validate("text@example.com"))


func email_validate(email:String) -> bool:
    if email.length() > 255:
        return false

    var email_regex := RegEx.new()
    email_regex.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_\u0060{|}~-]+@([^:/]+)$")
    var m := email_regex.search(email)
    if m == null:
        return false

    var domain_regex := RegEx.new()
    var domain_name_regex_str := "[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?"
    domain_regex.compile("^" + domain_name_regex_str + "(?:\\." + domain_name_regex_str + ")*$")
    if domain_regex.search(m.get_string(1)) == null:
        return false

    return true
```

Cómo puedes ver, utilizamos `get_string` para recuperar el grupo que capturamos (`([^:/]+)`) y validarlo con la segunda expresión regular. En particular `m.get_string(0)` nos daría toda la cadena (`"text@example.com"`) y `m.get_string(1)` nos daría lo que capturamos (`example.com`).

---

OK, si, es posible una sola expresión regular. Algo así:

```
func _ready():
    print(email_validate("text@example.com"))


func email_validate(email:String) -> bool:
    var email_regex := RegEx.new()  
    var domain_name_regex_str := "[a-zA-Z0-9](?:[a-zA-Z0-9-]{0,61}[a-zA-Z0-9])?"
    var domain_regex_str := domain_name_regex_str + "(?:\\." + domain_name_regex_str + ")*"
    email_regex.compile("^[a-zA-Z0-9.!#$%&'*+/=?^_\u0060{|}~-]+@" + domain_regex_str + "$")
    return email_regex.search(email) != null
```

*Tal vez quieras compilar de antemano las expresiones regulares, y tenerlas guardadas en variables, en lugar de compilarlas cada vez que las necesites.*